# Unary vs Stream benchmark

Tags: go, microservices, grpc

I'm start to play with some GRPC with Golang microservice applications.

After read the GRPC docs something is not clear to me:

> When to use Unary and when to use Streaming?

I mean, as example, i'm building a microservice that will parse a XLS and back JSON to stub. I will use a thrid-party lib to parse it for me. So, my job is to receive the xls, call lib and sent it forward. Quite simple.

What is the best pratice/performance that i can reach? Send() row by row with streaming or send whole parsed json once?

Answer (score 2):

Sending unary almost always faster.
Use streaming to send big files.

Answer (score 1):

Some benchmarks here: https://nshnt.medium.com/using-grpc-streams-for-unary-calls-cd64a1638c8a

Unless you expect to have very large files that will be processed asynchronously (line by line), unary must be the right choice.

There are arguments that theoretically, streams should have lower overhead. But that is not true. Streams ensure that messages are delivered in the order that they were sent, this would mean that if there are concurrent messages, there will be some kind of bottleneck.

**Use streams when**

- **You would otherwise need a polling** e.g. notifications, listening for events, sending data followed by deltas
- **Transactions** i.e lots of serial calls that must be served by a single server
- **A large call that can be broken down into multiple smaller request** e.g. file upload, text to speech translation

Some drawbacks of using streams:

- **Hard to load balance** ie. Will not automatically distribute load on new servers
- **Higher application level complexity**. Mapping client message with server response must be done by application
- **Intermittend network failures**. Even small interruptions in TCP connections will fail the connection. Application-level complexity to recover from intermittent network failures.
- **Maintains order for messages** You can't be writting multiple messages, so if you have many requests in pipeline, they will be have to be made sequentially.

Comment: "Hard to load balance" I'm having a hard time understanding this. load balancing isnt a built in function of grpc right? So why does this matter? If I have 3 grpc servers, even if I use streams, its doable for them to tell me which ones are handling more load than others.
Unless you mean "its hard to load balance since its one stream thus it can be weird to split across servers". i.e. 1 stream of 300 protos is harder to distribute than 300 RPCs?

Comment: Once a Stream is established, it is tied to a particular server. If you send 1000s of messages on that Stream, they will be sent to the same server instance. Unless that Server itself does load balancing, the messages will not be load balanced by grpc

Answer (score 0):

Unary is request/response. The client wants a service, it sends a request and receives a response. If there is a connection failure, the client has to send the same request again. On the client-side, Unary is fast and easy to implement.

In streaming, in the beginning, the client creates an RPC, sends multiple requests, and ends the connection. The typical example is, the client sends some notification to the server(like periodic gps coordinates or the state of a device). If there is a network failure, after reconnection, it's okay to start at that point without considering the previous states. You can replace streaming with multiple RPCs(you basically poll at regular intervals), it's slower than the unary, but the application complexity and cost of multiple unary RPCs is higher than one long-running streaming.

If the file is relatively big and can't fit into memory, you can use streaming. In the case of Unary, a disconnection will force a resend of the complete file. But since the application developer can indeed detect disconnection, either you resend the file or make sure each streaming message contains enough information, so that each part can be assembled to create the whole.

In your case, a big xls file to json fits into client streaming.